# Lock on Dispatcher

Tags: c#, wpf

```
lock
{
  Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Send, (SendOrPostCallback)delegate(object o)
 {
   DoSomething();
 }
}
```

Does lock remains acquired Until Dispatcher completes its execution or released soon after sending the DoSomething(); for execution to Dispatcher?

Comment: Is that hard to test yourself?

Comment: Why would you do that though? The invoke is going to be single threaded. Worst case is you end up in a deadlock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Lock remains acquired until code under `lock {}` section completes its execution.
- In your case that means: until `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` completes its execution.
- And as `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` executes asynchronously, that means that lock gets released almost "immediately" - `DoSomething()` might start in the moment when lock has been already released.

Comment: +1 My two cents: In this case `lock` is useless unless it is inside the `delegate` or `DoSomething`.